# looking for suggestions for a basic music media player

Tags: windows-7, mp3, media-player, wma

I'm not really sure where to start looking, but I'd need a basic mp3 & wma player for windows 7 (free if possible).  I don't want something that will waste my RAM and CPU, and I don't want to manage play-lists.  I just want to dump a bunch of mp3 & wma files into a single a directory and have them play randomly.

Comment: LOL, I didn't realize that everyone here was using windows media player and/or iTunes.  Call me a fool, but I thought the users here were more sophisticated than that.

Comment: Shopping questions/suggestions are off topic as per FAQ so this will likely be closed soon

Comment: @user231785 - Whats wrong with Media Player and/or VLC?

Comment: ha ha -5, I hope you can spend the points you "earn" on this web site, or get a cut of the ad revenue.  Oh, wait, you can't and don't.  So I guess you are free labor.  I guess you get what you pay for, and in my case that is almost nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer [WINAMP](http://www.winamp.com/media-player/en), but there are several other alternatives.  Lifehacker did a pretty good write up on what their user community considered the best.  [Link](http://lifehacker.com/5804911/the-best-music-player-application-for-windows) here.